# Cell.Formula is not recognised as a formula

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following VBA code to add a formula to a cell:

```
   Dim Rng As Range
   Dim cel As Range
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim AmountOfCells As Integer
   Dim varray As Variant
   Dim varrayValid As Variant
   Dim pctCompl1 As Single
   Dim pctCompl2 As Single
   Dim ref As Integer
   
   
   ' UPDATE COLUMN A
   
   Set Rng = Range("A12:A1521")
   ref = 9
    For Each cel In Rng.Cells
            With cel
                .Formula = "='Weekly Results'!E" & ref
                ref = ref + 1
            End With
            
    Next cel
```

'Weekly Results' refers to a valid sheet.

However, my formula is not being evaluated as a formula. When I manually select a cell, and from the menu bar choose 'Evaluate Formula' I get a message telling me that *"the current cell being evaluated contains a constant"*.

I have set the following in code `Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic`, and in `Options\Formulas\Workbook Calculation` is set to `Automatic`.

If I Find and Replace `'=` with `=`, then the formula will evaluate correctly.

Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Comment: Codes are fine and working for me. Did you declared variables correctly? Post you full code.

Comment: I have updated the post with a bit more of my code showing defs.

Comment: i have tried your code in my system it works fine. try to clear the range before you apply the formula. Use **Rng.Clear**  after **Set Rng = Range("A12:A1521")** if you don't have any formating issue involve.

Comment: Remove the "Text" formatting from the column A. Set to "General".

Answer (score 0):

Thank you mishu36, I added 'Rng.Clear' and it seems to have worked.

Comment: Yes, because it removes your "Text" formatting.